# Uploading dSYM/.symbols file to appstore connect automatically using shell script

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, dsym

Is there a way we can upload dSYM file when we upload .ipa file to TestFlight via shell script

```
xcrun altool --upload-app -f $ipa_path -u $appstore_connect_username -p $appstore_connect_password
```

If we do it manually using Xcode -> Window -> Organizer then it shows a checkbox (Upload your app's symbols to receive symbolicated reports from Apple) which is checked by default.

[image]

Since we have automated ipa uploading to testflight using above command, but dSYM is not uploading in that case. How can we upload dSYM to AppStoreConnect automatically?

**Note:** My iOS app project doesn't have bitcode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by setting `uploadSymbols` flag to `true` in `ExportOptions.plist`, while exporting .ipa file using the following command:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/myproject_results.xcarchive -exportPath ./build/ipa/ -exportOptionsPlist /path/to/ExportOptions.plist
```

So, when you upload your ipa using following command it will also upload symbols to app store connect.

```
xcrun altool --upload-app -f $ipa_path -u $appstore_connect_username -p $appstore_connect_password
```

You can verify existence of the symbols file in the exported .ipa using the following command:

```
unzip -lv $ipaPath | grep symbols
```

References:
[Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690094)